# Computed property for model instance dependend on all instances

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I would like to observe changes on each instance of a model. Given this little example, when the number of items changes for a category, the percent value should change for each other category. In this example it doesn't update the percentValue:

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
  name:        DS.attr('string'),
  items:       DS.hasMany('App.Item'),
  percentValue: function() {
    var total_items = App.Item.all().get('length')
    var category_items = this.get('items').get('length')

    return total_items == 0 ? 0 : (100 * category_items / total_items).toFixed()
  }.property('@each.items.length')
})

App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  name:         DS.attr('string'),
})

category = App.Category.createRecord({name: 'Category1'})
item = App.Item.createRecord({name: 'Item1'})

category.get('items').pushObject(item)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the computed property `percentValue` belongs in an `Ember.ArrayController` where you have access to `@each`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in the property dependency expression: You should have `items.@each`, not `@each.items.length`

```
...
}.property('items.@each')
```

---

You also could improve your code:

```
this.get('items').get('length')
```

may be written:

```
this.get('items.length')
```

---

Last, to insert a new relation member, you should call `createRecord`directly on the `items` relation, which will simplify & avoid the `pushObject` call.

```
category.get('items').createRecord({ name: 'Item1' })
```

Comment: it seems that `items.each` only observes the items of one category, and not of all categories. I want that if the tracks of CategoryA change, then the percentValue of CategoryB should be updated as well. Thanks a lot for the other tips :)

Comment: Indeed, `items.@each` will observe the category's items only. Did you tried `App.Item.all.length` or `@each.items.@each`?